# How can I make this property so it is only created when I first access it?

Tags: c#, lazy-evaluation

I have the following code:

```
/// <summary>
/// BrowserFactory responsible for deciding if you should receive a shared or isolated browser instance.
/// </summary>
public static class BrowserFactory
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Shared Browser Instance
    /// </summary>
    private static SharedBrowser _sharedBrowser;

    /// <summary>
    /// The window handle of the shared browser instance.
    /// </summary>
    private static string _sharedHwnd;

    /// <summary>
    /// The last thread id to access the shared browser.
    /// </summary>
    private static int _sharedThreadId;

    static BrowserFactory()
    {
        Shared= new SharedBrowser();
    }       

    private static SharedBrowser Shared
    {
        get
        {
            var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
            if (currentThreadId != _sharedThreadId)
            {
                _sharedBrowser = IE.AttachTo<SharedBrowser>(Find.By("hwnd", _sharedHwnd));
                _sharedThreadId = currentThreadId;
            }
            return _sharedBrowser;
        }
        set
        {
            _sharedBrowser = value;
            _sharedHwnd = _sharedBrowser.hWnd.ToString();
            _sharedThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
        }
    }

    public static Browser GetBrowser()
    {
        return BrowserSettings.UseSharedBrowser ? Shared : new Browser();
    }
}
```

How can I make it so I only instantiate the SharedBrowser object when the property is first accessed rather than in the constructor?

At first I thought to do it in the Shared property, but it seemed weird to be calling the a set from a properties get.

I also thought about having the _sharedBrowser be wrapped around in a .NET 4.0 Lazy object but then I'm not sure how to directly instantiate something wrapped in Lazy which is what I would need to do in the Shared property when a user gets (after the re-attaching).

I don't see how I could this without duplicating my Shared properties .set logic in the .get.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your browser factory is used by multiple threads?

Comment: @insipid, it is used by MSTest test methods, which by their nature are run from different threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern for static as well as for instance members:

```
private SomeType _myProperty;
public SomeType MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        if (_myProperty == null) {
            _myProperty = new SomeType();
        }
        return _myProperty;
    }
}
```

This is called lazy instantiation.

---

EDIT:

```
private static SharedBrowser _shared;
public static SharedBrowser Shared {
    get
    {
        var currentThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();          
        if _shared == null) {
            _shared = new SharedBrowser();
            _sharedHwnd = _sharedBrowser.hWnd.ToString();
            _sharedThreadId = currentThreadId;         
        }
        if (currentThreadId != _sharedThreadId) {          
            _sharedBrowser = IE.AttachTo<SharedBrowser>(Find.By("hwnd", _sharedHwnd));          
            _sharedThreadId = currentThreadId;          
        }          
        return _shared;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I going to have to duplicate the log of MyProperties .set in its .get?  If you look at my example there are several things I need to do when setting a new value (record threadid, window hwnd, etc).

Comment: There is no need for a setter, since you create the shared browser in the getter: `if (_sharedBrowser == null) sharedBrowser = new SharedBrowser();`, not in the constructor.

Comment: you aren't seeing my point.  Look at the setter of my property.  I have to do things when the underlying property _sharedBrowser is set.  I can't just new up a SharedBrowser() without duplicating my code in my set.

Comment: See my edit. You only need a getter. You don't need the code in the constructor.

Comment: @KingNestor: why do you need a setter? In the code you have provided, it's only used in one place: the constructor. @Olivier's solution moves all the construction logic to the getter. Unless there's a possibility of some other code (inside this class, since this is a private property) setting a different instance of `SharedBrowser` which needs to be configured, you do not need a setter.

Comment: I might also ask why you want to do this at all... are you trying to save time, or memory? This won't save you any time, since it's a static class: there's no possibility of the event happening more than once whether you create it lazy-like or not. It's probably better to do it at application start, rather than in response to input.

Comment: Unless there are senarios where the browser is not needed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about a static constructor is you know it will be called only once per application. You don't have that kind of guarantee later on. So add a static constructor and wrap your instantiation in a Lazy < T > in it, and then reference the Lazy's .Value in your .get

Comment: what about in my .set where I need to set the value of that lazy property?

Answer (score 0):

Store a private class level SharedBrowser variable, then check if its null in your get block.  Then to complete your extra initialization logic, refactor that into another method and call it from both the `get` and the `set`.

```
private static SharedBrowser _shared = null;

private static SharedBrowser Shared
{
    get
    {
        if(_shared == null)
        {
            _shared = new SharedBrowser();
            InitSharedBrowser();
        }

        // the rest of your code here.
    }
    set
    {
            _shared = value;
            InitSharedBrowser();
    }
}

private static void InitSharedBrowser()
{
    // your SharedBrowser Initialization logic goes here.
}
```

Comment: If you look, in my Shared's set, there are things I need to do when assigning a browser.  I need to record the current thread id, window hwnd, etc.

I basically need to call my .set from my .get which seems weird.

Comment: Refactor that logic into another method (or the constructor of `SharedBrowser`, if you can), then call that method from the get and the set.